# How can I pass functions to the macros in elixir?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm working on a module which expands functionalities of other modules when `use`d. The problem is that sometimes I want to write some custom code in module definition which is used to boost module functionality:

So, it looks like:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote unquote: false do
      # a lot of code
      model
      |> unquote(@callback)
      |> another_bunch_of_things_in_pipe
    end
  end
end
```

And my module

```
defmodule Poor do
  use Included

  @callback fn(model) -> %{ model | poor: true } end
end
```

Not surprisingly, I have a `invalid quoted expression: #Function<0.100338 in file:web/models/user.ex>`. I found Jose Valim mention that it's impossible to unquote anonymous function.

So, can you introduce me good approach to pass and invoke custom code into macros in elixir?

Answer (score 4):

The `quote` is running in the context of the `Poor` module, so you don't need to unquote the module attribute. However, `@callback` is reserved for internal use, so you will need to use a different name:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      @callback_fun.()
    end
  end
end

defmodule Poor do
  @callback_fun fn -> IO.puts "hello from callback" end
  use Included
end
```

You can also pass the function as an argument to `use`, which I think is a bit cleaner because it directly shows where the function is used:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    fun = Keyword.get(opts, :callback)
    quote bind_quoted: [fun: fun] do
      fun.()
    end
  end
end

defmodule Poor do
  use Included, callback: fn ->
    IO.puts "hello from callback"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code (aside from the missing `end` to the `fn` which is probably a typo):

- `@callback` is a special attribute in Elixir. You can read more about it [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html). You'll have to use another name.
- The syntax to assign something to a module attribute is `@attr value`, not `@attr = value`.
- You don't need to `unquote` the attribute, you can just pipe into `@attr.()`.
- As `__using__` is invoked as soon as you call `use`, you need to declare the attribute before calling `use`.

Here's the fixed version:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      model = %{poor: false}
      model
      |> @back.()
      |> IO.inspect
    end
  end
end

defmodule Poor do
  @back fn(model) -> %{ model | poor: true } end
  use Included
end
```

Output:

```
%{poor: true}
```